# Escapar '' en una consulta sql con node

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, nodejs

Quiero obtener un solo registro con la siguiente consulta

```
controller.store = (req, res) => {
const id = req.id;
let serie = 1;
let codigo = req.body.per_codigo;
req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error de conexión perifericoController@store');
        res.redirect('back');
    }
    conn.query('select idperiferico from periferico where per_serie = ?', serie, (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error al obtener el registro');
            res.redirect('back');
        }
        console.log(row[0].idperiferico);
    })
})
```

}

La consulta anterior me devuelve mas de un registro dado que todos inician con el número 1, entonces quiero obtener el registro que sea exactamente igual a '1' , me parece que debo escapar de alguna forma las comillas.

Comment: per_serie es numerico?

Answer (score 0):

Encierra entre corchetes todos los parámetros que serán remplazado por (?) de la siguiente forma: [serie]. Así he trabajado yo y no he tenido ningún inconveniente, pero es raro lo que te esta sucediendo, asegúrate también de que el tipo de dato sea el correcto.

```
controller.store = (req, res) => {
const id = req.id;
let serie = 1;
let codigo = req.body.per_codigo;
req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error de conexión perifericoController@store');
        res.redirect('back');
    }
    conn.query('select idperiferico from periferico where per_serie = ?', [serie], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error al obtener el registro');
            res.redirect('back');
        }
        console.log(row[0].idperiferico);
    })
})
```

Comment: tendré mas cuidado en la redacción. Gracias